# How to create view in mongodb using spring data mongo db

Tags: java, spring-data-mongodb

How to create view in mongodb using spring data mongodb?
Thanks

Answer (score 3):

You can inject bean of type org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate where you need it and use one of its methods **executeCommand**, for example [executeCommand(String jsonCommand)](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/mongodb/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/mongodb/core/MongoTemplate.html#executeCommand-java.lang.String-) in folowing manner:

```
mongoTemplate.executeCommand("{ create: <view>, viewOn: <source>, pipeline: <pipeline> }");
```