# How do I create a view using spring-data-mongodb without resorting to mongoTemplate.executeCommand(..)?

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, spring-data-mongodb

So I know [how to create a view using `mongoTemplate.executeCommand(..)`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59769086/2936460). However, that leaves me having to define the view in a string.

Spring-data-mongodb allows for defining pipeline stages using [`Aggregation.project(..)`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/mongodb/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/mongodb/core/aggregation/Aggregation.html#project-java.lang.String...-) and its kin. But how do I put those together and create a view? I read there *should* be an option to pass to [`createCollection(String, CollectionOptions)`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/mongodb/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/mongodb/core/MongoOperations.html#createCollection-java.lang.String-org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.CollectionOptions-), but if there is, I can't find it.

So is there a way to create a view in spring-data-mongodb without resorting to `mongoTemplate.executeCommand(..)`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is not yet - please follow [PR#4142](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-mongodb/pull/4142) for updates. This will allow you to use template API along with the Aggregation Framework to create views.

```java
template.createView("firstYears", Student.class, match(where("year").is(1)));
```